# Minimum DNF length of a conjuction of equivalences

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, formal-methods, normal-forms

Show that the formula $\bigcap_{i=1}^n (X_i \leftrightarrow Y_i)$ cannot have an equivalent disjunctive normal form with less than $2^n$ clauses.

I am puzzled on what approach to take -- whether to consider the equivalent boolean functions or some depth trees or some specific example of $X_i$-s and $Y_i$-s in order to get a proof. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Try to answer this question: let $D$ be a DNF representation of your formula and $C$ be a clause of $D$. Is it possible that $C$ does not contain the variable $X_1$?

Comment: Ok, we observe that in the initial formula changing the value of $X_1$ (while all other variables are fixed) changes the value of $X_1 \leftrightarrow Y_1$ and hence can make the overall result false if it was previously true. Now if the DNF has only satisfiable clauses (if there are unsatisfiable, just remove them, as OR is not affected by FALSE) and there is one without $X_1$ then it should always be true for some choice of the other variables, contradiction.

Comment: Right, this is symmetric for $X_i$ and $Y_i$. What can you conclude for a given clause $C$ of $D$? How can you conclude?

Comment: @holf so if I am not mistaken, after restricting to satisfiable clauses only, each clause has to contain all of $X_1,\ldots,X_n, Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ (perhaps with some negations on some variables). How to continue now?

Comment: Ok by setting $X_1 = Y_1 = 0$ and everything else to be $1$ in the initial formula shows that there must be a clause containing the negations of $X_1$ and $Y_1$, right? (And similarly for all other $(X_i,Y_i)$.) And also $X_1$ and $Y_1$ themselves, by setting $X_1 = Y_1 = 1$ instead.

Comment: So how many satisfying assignment of $D$ is covered by a given clause $C$? How many clauses do you need to cover every satisfying assignment of $D$? I think you can answer your own question now.

Comment: 1 satisfying per clause (since each clause is a conjuction) while $2^n$ in the given formula (we have to have $Y_i = X_i$ and then the $X_i$-s can be anything, two choices for each). Thanks a lot again!